# ASUS RT-AX82U Router not showing all clients

Tags: router, asus

I found this thread here: [Why do some devices not show up in the connected clients list on my Asus RT-AC68U router?](https://superuser.com/questions/1531367/why-do-some-devices-not-show-up-in-the-connected-clients-list-on-my-asus-rt-ac68?newreg=4176db994b6c4139b4626ea6af8ba0aa) but could not comment on it.

I am having the same issue with my ASUS RT-AX82U router. Not all clients (mac addresses IP addresses) are registering on the client list. Is this an ASUS router issue, or is this an ALL router issue, including Netgear and Linksys? I have a Linksys WRT3200AC router setup too, but do not use it much.

I used to have a Netgear AX Nighthawk router, but had nothing but problems with it and fired it and switched to the ASUS RT-AX82U router.

As a ham radio operator, I set up a FLEX 6400 software defined radio. And connected to my Ethernet cable and connected it to my home network. The FLEX 6400 is the Mac address that is not registering on the client list. It does not show up DHCP or Static. I made two YouTube videos here:

1. https://youtu.be/i8snoFSWdms
2. https://youtu.be/N5T0c7k7-7w

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser . The question you linked to, offers explanations on this occurrence. Have you reviewed them all? If you did, then you should [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1793461/edit) and add why those explanations aren't enough for you

Comment: According to the [manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/2032361/Flexradio-Systems-Flex-6400.html?page=31), connecting the FLEX 6400 to the router should work, and it should advertise itself on the network. Try to temporarily disable your firewall.

Comment: As to the reason you were unable to comment on the protected question, that was done, to additional comments submitted as an answer from being submitted. Having information about your problem in your question instead of a YouTube video is advisable

Comment: This device is connected by WiFi or through an Ethernet connection?